# Calculate percentage of occurrence of a factor of the total amount of occurrences of a group factor

Tags: r, group-by, percentage, absolute

I have a sample dataset:

```
Species <-c("Bass", "Bass", "Bass", "Bass", "Bass", "Bass","Bass","Bass","Bass")
FishID <- c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a3","a3","a3","a3")
Prey <- c("Amphipoden", "Mysis", "Polychaeten", "Amphipoden", "Mysis", "Amphipoden","Mysis","Polychaeten","Mollusca")

df <- data.frame(Species, FishID, Prey)
```

For having Bass as a predator, there are 3 unique individual Basses as different FishID: a1, a2 and a3. I would like to calculate the absolute percentage of occurrence of a prey species per FishID (individual Bass).

So in this case:
Amphipods occurs 3 times, so 100% in the stomachs of Bass (found in all three of the individuals), for Mysis idem. For polychaete however, is found only two times in the stomach of Bass: so this would be then 66,6%. And Moluscs are only found one time, so 33,3 %

As an end result, I am looking for something like this:

```
Species <-c("Bass", "Bass", "Bass", "Bass")
Prey <- c("Amphipoden", "Mysis", "Polychaeten", "Mollusca")
Percentage <- c(100, 100, 66,6, 33,3)
df2 <- data.frame(Species,Prey, Percentage)
```

I tried this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Species,Prey) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(percent = n / sum(n) * 100)
```

But it isn't giving me hat I want.

Anty help is welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  # only count Prey once per Species/FishID (which I presume always go together)
  distinct(Species, FishID, Prey) |>
  mutate(count = 1) |>
  # complete with missing combinations for each FishID
  complete(nesting(Species, FishID), Prey, fill = list(count = 0)) |> 
  summarize(percent = sum(count) / n(), .by = c(Species, Prey))


# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Species Prey        percent
  <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>
1 Bass    Amphipoden    1    
2 Bass    Mollusca      0.333
3 Bass    Mysis         1    
4 Bass    Polychaeten   0.667
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change a little point: Instead of dividing by `sum(n)`, you have to divide by `length(unique(FishID))` in order to get the correct number of individual `FishID`. Also note that the last element of `FishID` has to be `a3`, not `A3`.

```
library(dplyr)

FishID <- c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a3","a3","a3","a3")

df %>%
    summarise(n = n(), .by = Prey) %>%
    mutate(percent = n / length(unique(FishID)) * 100)

         Prey n   percent
1  Amphipoden 3 100.00000
2       Mysis 3 100.00000
3 Polychaeten 2  66.66667
4    Mollusca 1  33.33333
```

Comment: That worked as well! What if I want to ad a "grouped_by"?

Comment: You can do this. I used the "shortcut" here, i.e., `.by = Prey` in the `summarise` verb. However, you also can delete the shortcut and write the `group_by` as in your question, it will lead to the same result. Also note that grouping by `Species` is not necessary here since `Species` contains only one distinct element.